# Fluid trainer for an intermediate rider

Tags: rollers

Because of the Xmas sales some internet shops started making offers on roll trainers. My target area would be an intermediate machine, something that I would use an hour or so daily, with two-three hours rides once per week (the actual usage of the trainer will be lower as I tend to alter biking with jogging, swimming, and work-outs/yoga in the gym).

Currently I narrowed down my search to these models:

- [Kurt Kinetic Road Machine II T2200](http://www.amazon.de/Kurt-Kinetic-Road-Machine-2014/dp/B00F4TVDJY/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1418313826&sr=8-1&keywords=Kurt%20Kinetic%20Road%20Machine%20Fluid): 330 Euro
- [Tacx Rollentrainer T-2200 Flow](https://shop.zweirad-stadler.de/Fahrrad-Teile/Rollentrainer/Tacx-Rollentrainer-T-2200-Flow.html): 200 Euro
- [Tacx Ergotrainer T2220 Flow Multiplayer VR Trainer](https://shop.zweirad-stadler.de/Fahrrad-Teile/Rollentrainer/Tacx-Ergotrainer-T2220-Flow-Multiplayer-VR-Trainer.html) : 333 Euro
- [2014 Cycleops Fluid Turbo Trainer Fluid 2](http://www.amazon.de/2014-Cycleops-Fluid-Turbo-Trainer/dp/B00EPM7T1M/ref=sr_1_1?s=sports&ie=UTF8&qid=1418336770&sr=1-1&keywords=Cycleops%20Fluid%20Turbo%20Trainer%20Fluid%202): 300 Euro

I am a frequent half-marathon runner and passionat mountain and road-biker. Currently, I am training for a marathon. Any comments, which model should I opt? As one may notice, I opt for a machine that is around 300 Euro.

Comment: Why not magnetics? I understand they claim to have realistic road feel, but when you're doing intervals then all that matters is the resistance or braking power.

Comment: On the net one can find quite a thorough discussion on fluid vs. magnetic. I chose fluid because of the noise and max resistence it will offer

Comment: I've been through the debate. I'm actually wondering if you've decided yet because the Tacx Flow you have in your options is actually an electro brake, not fluid (which I believe better than fluid ;) see http://www.tacx.com/en/products/trainers/flow I have an old satori (magnetic) it's no more noisy than fluid (tried cyclops), just tyre noise.

Comment: @imel96: thanks for the note that the trax model T2200 is not the fluid one. Speaking of the devil, I was able to test this model in a bike shop on Saturday and was rather positively impressed by the machine. In terms of breaking power: that should be more than enough for me, right? Any comments/impressions/opinions would be highly valuable..

Comment: Just want to comment on the fluid type, since it simulates road condition, I couldn't do slow pedalling and have high resistance at the same time even in top gear. Where with Tacx (or other magnetic) I can adjust the braking power with the switch. Could be important if you do that kind of interval.

Comment: This question was flagged for review as off-topic. It's not a bad question but "shopping" or product recommendation questions are generally a poor fit for a Q&A site like this because the answers frequently become out of date as manufacturers change their product lines. See [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally I had a wind trainer which was very loud and the resistance felt weird. You could pedal really quickly and it would get really easier. I've had a Kurt Kinetic Road Machine for a couple of years and have road it about 40 times, putting about 1000km on it. It is quite, still looks brand new and doesn't get easier the longer I pedal which is a problem with some lower end trainers. This is because the fluid doesn't warm up and become less viscous. I would strongly recommend it. Also the resistance feels similar to riding on the road. Another benefit of a Kurt Kinetic is that you can translate your speed into watts. I bought a power meter and have compared the numbers and they are about 5% difference, so pretty close. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for a comment. It's great to have a user with direct exprience. Due to a low interest into a question, I cross posted the question at [mtbr](http://forums.mtbr.com/general-discussion/fluid-trainer-intermediate-rider-942217.html). The Kurt Kinetic Road Machine seems to be a preference for many riders :)